# Product Of Factors

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The following is from the UK textbook [CGP A-Level Maths 2017-2018](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/178294723X). Exercise 2.2 Q3 part d.

The question asks that you express the following as the product of factors.

$$l^2m(a - 2x) + rp^2(2x - a)$$

The answer given is

$$(a - 2x)(l^2m - rp^2)$$

It appears to me that the second part of the equation, $rp^2(2x - a)$, has been multiplied by -1 which gives

$$l^2m(a - 2x) - rp^2(a - 2x)$$

And then from that, the answer is easy to deduce.

My question is that it does not seem valid to apply the -1 to just part of the expression?

Comment: The second part of the equation has not been multiplied by -1: it has been multiplied by 1 (which is obviously a valid thing to do), but in a slightly tricky way: recall that $1 =( -1) \times (-1)$, so they take one of the -1s and apply it to $(2x -a)$ and take the other -1  and  multiply the $rp^2$ by it, thereby changing the sign in front.

Comment: Thank you @NickD your explanation clarified it for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has *not* been multiplied by $-1$.  Note the order of $a-2x$ and $2x -a$.

The thing is $2x-a = -(a-2x)$

So all they have actually done is *substituted* $2x -a$ with $-(a-2x)$ (and no multiplication was done) so

$l^2m(a - 2x) + rp^2\color{red}{(2x - a)}=$

$l^2m(a-2x) + rp^2\color{blue}{[-(a-2x)]} = $

$l^2m(a-2x) \color{blue}{-} rp^2\color{blue}{(a-2x)}$

and the rest follows

FWIW, you are correct:  It would *not* have been valid to apply an application to just one part of an expression.  That would have been outright *wrong*.  But substituting a section with something that is equal to that section is common, perfectly valid and, at times, strategically necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Just
$$l^2m(a - 2x) + rp^2(2x - a)=l^2m(a - 2x) - rp^2(a-2x)=(a-2x)(l^2m-rp^2)$$

Answer (score 0):

All you need to see is that $(2x-a)=-(a-2x)$

The rest follows nicely